# How to suppress a proc's return value in tcl prompt

Tags: tcl, return-value

I'm relatively new in TCL, in TCL prompt, when we invoke a proc with some return value, the proc's return value is echoed back by tcl. Is there a way to stop it (without affecting puts or similar functionality) as an example

```
bash$ tclsh
% proc a {} { puts  "hello"; return 34; }
% a
hello
34
%
```

Now how do i suppress the 34 coming to the screen? Any help is appreciated.

Update: 
Actually the proc is a part of another tool, earlier it did not have any return value, but now conditionally it can return a value. 
it can be called from a script and there won't be any problem (as Bryan pointed out). and it can be called from interactive prompt, then after all the necessary outputs, the return value is getting printed unnecessarily. 
So 1) I don't have the facility of changing a user's tclshrc 2) existing scripts should continue to work. 
And it seems strange that every time the proc is called, after all the necessary outputs, a number gets printed. To a user, this is a needless information unless he has caught the value and wants to do something. So i wanted the value to be delivered to user, but without getting printed to prompt/UI (hope i'm clear )

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do that. Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: Why is this important? Are you aware this is a feature of the interactive shell and not something you would notice when running a file-based script?

Comment: That's how tclsh works. Change the C source code, build a tclsh without this behaviour and offer it to your users as an alternative tclsh.

Comment: A chameleon question. You just disqualified most of the answers.

Comment: Well i'm actually new in scripting, but does not it seems strange? take the following snippet 
`
    % proc a {} { return 34; }
    % set b [a]
    34
    % puts $b
    34
    % catch a rr
    0
    % puts $rr
    34 
`
Why the set b [a] printed a's return value. if it is supposed to print anything, it should print the return value of set command. as it is printing in case catch is used

Comment: the result of the `set` command is the new value. `set a [set b [set c 34]]` sets a, b and c to 34. With some tricks ([`trace`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm)) it can return a different value than the result from `a`

Comment: To put it another way: it's not printing a's return value. It's printing set's return value.

Answer (score 3):

The interactive shell code in `tclsh` and `wish` will print any non-empty result. To get nothing printed, you have to have the last command on the “line” produce an empty result. But which command to use?

Many commands will produce an empty result:

```
if 1 {}
subst ""
format ""
```

However, the shortest is probably:

```
list
```

Thus, you could write your code like:

```
a;list
```

Of course, this only really becomes useful when your command *actually* produces a large result that you don't want to see. In those cases, I often find that it is most useful to use something that measures the size of the result, such as:

```
set tmp [something_which_produces a_gigantic result]; string length $tmp
```

The most useful commands I find for that are `string length`, `llength` and `dict size`.

---

If you absolutely *must* not print the result of the command, you have to write your own interactive loop. There are two ways to do this, depending on whether you are running inside the event loop or not:

### Without the event loop

This simplistic version just checks to see if the command name is in what the user typed. It's probably not a good idea to arbitrarily throw away results otherwise!

```
set accum ""
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    append accum $line "\n"
    if {[info complete $accum]} {
        if {[catch $accum msg]} {
            puts stderr $msg
        } elseif {$msg ne "" && ![string match *TheSpecialCommand* $accum]} {
            puts $msg
        }
        set accum ""
    }
}
```

### With the event loop

This is just handling the blocking IO case; that's the correct thing when input is from a cooked terminal (i.e., the default)

```
fileevent stdin readable handleInput
set accum ""
proc handleInput {} {
    global accum
    if {[gets stdin line] < 0} {
        exit; # Or whatever
    }
    append accum $line "\n"
    if {[info complete $accum]} {
        if {[catch {uplevel "#0" $accum} msg]} {
            puts stderr $msg
        } elseif {$msg ne "" && ![string match *TheSpecialCommand* $accum]} {
            puts $msg
        }
        set accum ""
    }
}
vwait forever; # Assuming you're not in wish or have some other event loop...
```

### How to detect the command is being executed

The code above uses `![string match *TheSpecialCommand* $accum]` to decide whether to throw away the command results, but this is very ugly. A more elegant approach that leverages Tcl's own built-in hooks is to use an [execution trace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/trace.htm#M9) to detect whether the command has been called (I'll just show the non-event-loop version here, for brevity). The other advantage of this is that it is simple to extend to suppressing the output from multiple commands: just add the trace to each of them.

```
trace add execution TheSpecialCommand enter SuppressOutput
proc SuppressOutput args {
    # Important; do not suppress when it is called inside another command
    if {[info level] == 1} {
        set ::SuppressTheOutput 1
    }
}

# Mostly very similar from here on
set accum ""
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    append accum $line "\n"
    if {[info complete $accum]} {
        set SuppressTheOutput 0;                       # <<<<<< Note this!
        if {[catch $accum msg]} {
            puts stderr $msg
        } elseif {$msg ne "" && !$SuppressTheOutput} { # <<<<<< Note this!
            puts $msg
        }
        set accum ""
    }
}
```

To be clear, I wouldn't *ever* do this in my own code! I'd just suppress the output manually if it mattered.

Comment: You can also write your own read-eval-print-loop (without the print part) if you want. That's more work than is usually justified.

Comment: as per my update, i have to deliver the return value silently. So even i write a wrapper around the original proc, it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @abasu It's not nice to change the requirements so substantially on people (ask another question instead!) but I hope my extended answer addresses how to do it. Note that you *have* to use your own interaction loop to do this sort of trick. (Execution traces can't change the output of a command other than by throwing an error, which you probably don't want to do!)

Comment: I understand initial problem description was inadequate. Actually i thought this would be simple setting some verbosity level. After the first barrage of posts, i understood the mistake and updated the description. Anyway, thanks for your post. It seems to be the best/only approach for me (unless i change the c code and build another tclsh :) )

Answer (score 1):

You could make an empty procedure in .tclshrc...

```
proc void {} {}
```

...and when you don't need a return value, end the line with `;void`.

Answer (score -1):

Use **tcl_interactive** variable to enable the return of of the value, although I'm not sure where this would be useful...

```
proc a {} {
    puts "hello"
    if { [info exist tcl_interactive] } {
        return {};
    } else {
        return 34;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should not only check if the variable exist. `tcl_interactive` is in his case always `1`. Consider using `info level` too.

Comment: well as per my update, i need the return value to be delivered silently. So even if it is interactive mode, i need a return value, what i don't want is to tcl prompt echoing back that value

Comment: @abasu: Ok, I thought you only needed the return value if you used it non-interactively. So using the tcl prompt is part of your standard work procedure...

Comment: @Kuhn: I've checked this with running it in either a shell (with #!/usr/bin/tclsh on top) and running it as part of a source-command. For that purpose, it works.