# How to keep commands quiet in TCL?

Tags: tcl

How to execute `set` command without printing output on the screen? I want to read a file without displaying the contents on the screen.

```
set a [open "giri.txt" r]
set b [read $ifile]
```

Comment: Put it in a script, it is only displayed in the interactive interpreter

Comment: Also discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742838/how-to-suppress-a-procs-return-value-in-tcl-prompt).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're observing is just the standard behaviour of an *interactive* Tcl shell: each Tcl command returns a result value, and a return code.  If the Tcl shell is interactive (that is, its input and output streams are connected to a terminal), after executing each command, the string representation of the result value the command returned is printed, and then the prompt is shown again.  If the shell is not interactive, no results are printed and no prompt is shown.

(On a side note, such behaviour is ubiquitous with interpreters — various Unix shells, Python and Ruby interpreters do the same thing.)

If you want to inhibit such printouts in an interactive session (comes in handy from time to time), a simple hack to achieve that is to chain the command you want to "silence" with a "silent" command (producing a value whose string representation is an empty string), for instance:

```
set a [open "giri.txt" r]; list
```

Here, the list returned by the `list` command having no arguments is an empty list whose string representation is an empty string.  In an interactive shell, this chain of commands will output literally nothing.

It bears repeating that such a hack might only ever be needed in an *interactive* session — do not use it in *scripts.*

Comment: The cost in a script with the tip of the trunk is zero; the useless `list` at the end will end up converted into a `nop` by the optimizer.

Answer (score 4):

In Mentor ModelSim Tcl it is possible to do:

```
quietly set answer 42
```

Also in Mentor Questa:

```
help quietly
```

> The quietly command turns off transcript echoing for the specified command.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn this off in an interactive tclsh

```
set tcl_interactive false
```

but that will also turn off the prompt.